# how to set by default descending order of datatable string date column using jquery asp.net c#

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have troubles ordering table columns by date using Jquery Datatable

it's an Dynamic Table, I have column 'Week Date' displaying the date.

By default the 'Week Date' column data I'm getting like this `2023-06-29T00:00:00` and as per my requirement I have changed the format like this `29-Jun-2023`

And I used this logic for date format

```
 var timestamp = jsonData[i]["WeekDate"] //2023-06-29T00:00:00 {getting this format};
 const date = new Date(timestamp);
 const options = { day: 'numeric', month: 'short', year: 'numeric' };
 const formattedDate = date.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', options).replace(/ /g, '-');
 jsonData[i]["WeekDate"] = formattedDate //29-Jun-2023 (my required format);
```

Originally getting the `Week Date`:

And I have checked the `typeof` the column using `console.log(jsonData[i]["WeekDate"]); and console.log(typeof (jsonData[i]["WeekDate"]));` it shown like below image {string}.

[image: Type of column]

After changing the `Week Date` format:

I have checked the `typeof` the column using `console.log(formattedDate); and console.log(typeof (formattedDate));` it shown like below image {string}.

[image: type of column after change]

Example datatable structure:

```
<table id="datatable_clientwise" class="table responsive nowrap table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
             <thead>
             <tr>
              <th>Week Date</th>
              <th>Total Lots</th>
              <th>Turnover</th>
              <th>Investment</th>
              <th>Week PL</th>
              <th>Weekly Returns %</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td>04-Jun-2023</td>
              <td>36</td>
              <td>84848.44</td>
              <td>900000</td>
              <td>23444</td>
              <td>0.99</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>04-May-2023</td>
              <td>36</td>
              <td>84848.44</td>
              <td>900000</td>
              <td>23444</td>
              <td>0.99</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>10-Jun-2023</td>
              <td>36</td>
              <td>84848.44</td>
              <td>900000</td>
              <td>23444</td>
              <td>0.99</td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

And I have used this logic for datatable column sorting

```
$("#datatable_clientwise").DataTable().destroy();
    $('#datatable_clientwise').DataTable({
        "data": jsonData,
        "autoWidth": true,
        "info": false,
        "paging": false,
        "searching": false,
        "order": [[0, "desc"]],

        "columns":
            [
                { data: 'WeekDate' },
                { data: 'TotalLots' },
                { data: 'Turnover' },
                { data: 'Investment' },
                { data: 'WeekPL' },
                { data: 'ROI' },
            ],

        //order: [[1, 'DESC']],
    });
```

The final output is coming like this

[image: Not sorted]

By default `Week Date` column not sorted (descending order)

Suggest me where I did the mistake and why date column is not sorting properly.
Am I did any mistake at formatting the date logic ?
Please guide me.